# Why I am getting padding of 2px in my Lightning-radio-group element's all the radio button except first radio in LWC in salesforce?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-design-system, salesforcedx-cli

CSS:

```
.vertical-radio-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-left: var(--slds-c-lightning-radio-group-spacing-inline-start, 0rem);

}

.slds-radio {
  background-color: var(--slds-c-radio-color-background, rgb(127, 237, 10));}
```

---

[image]

---

HTML:

```
<lightning-radio-group
                    label={label.CCWIS_EcityLabel} 
                    options={city}
                    required
                    type="radio"
                    class="vertical-radio-group slds-radio"
                    name="city__c"
                    onchange={handleChange}
                    variant="label-hidden"
                    message-when-value-missing={invalidcity}>
</lightning-radio-group>
```

---

Please Help, Since I tried all the variations of code I can but nothing is working for me.

---

one of my variations : (Not working)

```
.slds-radio .slds-radio:is(:first-child) {
  margin-left: var(--slds-c-radio-Spacing-inline-start, 2rem);
}
```

Comment: you want all of them to be 2px padding on the left?